# IMAPSSLStore replaces "=" with "&#x3D;"

Tags: java, scala, email, imap

In our test we read email from gmail servers using IMAP. The problem is in fact that in gmail.com it looks like this:

```
To complete the registration process, click the http://xxx/#/confirmation?confirmationCode=OGM0Njg2ODktOTY0Ni00ZDViLTkzYWUtYjQzYzllMjY3NjMw
```

But when we get these emails through imap, it turns into this:

```
To complete the registration process, click the http://xxx/#/confirmation?confirmationCode&#x3D;OGM0Njg2ODktOTY0Ni00ZDViLTkzYWUtYjQzYzllMjY3NjMw
```

And it breaks our test. Is there any reason why it breaks space and how can we fix it?

**UPD** 
This is the code:
(it's in scala but I think it's readable for java developers too, store has type IMAPSSLStore)

```
val props = new Properties() {
  setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps")
}
val session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)
val store = session.getStore()
try {
  store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "ouremail", "ourpassword")

  val inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox")
  inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY)

  val msgCount = inbox.getMessageCount
  val latestMessages = inbox.getMessages(math.max(msgCount - 100, 1), msgCount)

  val message = inbox.search(new RecipientTerm(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient)), latestMessages)
    .headOption
    .map(_.getContent match {
      case str: String => str
      case is: InputStream => Source.fromInputStream(is).mkString
    })
```

Comment: Isn't that just the HTML-code for '='? Can the link still be followed if it is replaced?

Comment: no, it doesn't recognize it after that replacement